# Simple Hack Mechanism

Tags: security, testing, scripting, automated-tests, penetration-testing

I would like to know if there's an easy way on automating an attack to a certain page which only has 2 page elements:

-1 numeric field with 5 digit limitation 
-a submit button

Basically, if the user pressed the submit button, the system validates the digits entered and if it matches the system requirements, it will let the user go to the next page.

Does this kind of hack thing exist? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That depends on how that validation is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

You can do it using brute-force attack which tries all the possible numbers from 00000 to 99999 (all the 5 digit numbers) in your case and will submit and check. If you're using Mozilla Firefox browser, you can use Fireforce add-on to brute force. In Linux, Hydra is one of the best tools used for brute-forcing. You can also install Hydra in Windows and do the same. Hydra supports multiple protocols like HTTP, FTP, etc and makes the work easy for you.
See this for reference on how to install Hydra in Windows : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6fEAhBM8_8

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!